# How can Jeff answer a Community Wiki question with non-CW status?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, community-wiki

How can Jeff answer Community Wiki question with non-CW status on following question?

[How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste)

OP's Question

[image]

Jeff's Answer

[image]

Comment: sorry, figured that out myself, I should have looked deep before asking it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon) was not converted to wiki until [October 7, 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53598/revisions).

(Even if it had been wiki when Jeff answered, at that time the CW checkbox on answers always appeared. Thus it was possible to post non-wiki answers to wiki questions.)

When questions are migrated, their entire history is compressed into a single revision on the target site, so that's why the first revision here is the one that shows the wiki status.